# Extra command in subfig package

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I would like an extra command to be run in the captions using the `\subfloat` command from the `subfig` package. With normal captions, I just redefine `\captionfont`, but this doesn't work for captions of subfloats.

I have tried (the command I want to run is `\sansmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize\sffamily}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage[textfont=sf]{subfig}
\let\bensubfloat\subfloat
\renewcommand{\subfloat}[2][]{\bensubfloat[\sansmath #1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Subcaption $1+1$]{\framebox[3cm]{First}} \hfill
    \subfloat[Subcaption $1+a$]{\framebox[3cm]{Second}}
    \caption{Main caption} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This gives the desired output, but also many errors.

Comment: Please do not re-define \captionfont. It's still possible (and working fine most times) for compatibility reasons to version 1.4 of the caption package, but it's obsolete. Please use \captionsetup{font=...} instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like you want to have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath,subfig}
\DeclareCaptionFont{sansmath}{\sansmath}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize,sf,sansmath}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{font={footnotesize,sf,sansmath}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Subcaption $1+a$]{\framebox[3cm]{First}} \hfill
    \subfloat[Subcaption $1+b$]{\framebox[3cm]{Second}}
    \caption{Main caption $1+x$} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code uses \DeclareCaptionFont which is offered by the caption package for exactly this purpose - using own commands (like \sansmath) for caption or sub-caption font settings.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize\sffamily}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\makeatletter
\long\def\sf@@subfloat[#1]{%
    \@ifnextchar [%  %] match left bracket
      {\sf@@@subfloat{sub\@captype}[{\sansmath #1}]}%
      {\sf@@@subfloat{sub\@captype}[\@empty{#1}][{\sansmath #1}]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Subcaption $1+1$]{\framebox[3cm]{First}} \hfill
    \subfloat[Subcaption $1+a$]{\framebox[3cm]{Second}}
    \caption{Main caption} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm too halfhearted but personally I don't like redefining internal macros if this isn't necessary at all. (And if the redefinition makes trouble I got a support e-mail where I have to guess what the heck the original purpose of the redefinition could be ;-)) The caption package offers the macro \DeclareCaptionFont for this purpose. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Protect fragile commands within moving arguments:

```
\renewcommand{\subfloat}[2][]{\bensubfloat[\protect\sansmath #1]{#2}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I have edited the question and added a minimal example. The \protect command messed things up (the subcaptions appear twice and the positioning is wrong).

Comment: It is necessary to fix the errors. However, `\sansmath` doesn't seem to work well here. I would try the `subcaption` package instead of `subfig`.